# I am trying to access the previous state when i click this button but it does not seem to be working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to access the previous state but it keeps returning the same number please help

```
      let scrollUp = () => {


        setItems(prevnumberOfItems => prevnumberOfItems + 1000);
        alert(numberOfItems)
        window.scrollBy(0, -numberOfItems);
        alert(numberOfItems);
        setCounter(counter + 1);
        console.log(counter);
      };
```

I keep getting the same number back in setItems and setBeforeItems

```
     setItems(productRowLength * 530 + mobile);
      setbeforeItems(prevnumberOfItems => prevnumberOfItems + 1000);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately/54069332#54069332)

Comment: thanks i will look at this

Answer (score 0):

`setState` offers a callback function so if we do something like this -:

```
this.setState({someValue: 10});
console.log(this.state.someValue); //can't expect it to be 10, can be previous value too because setState is async.
```

but if we do something like this -:

```
this.setState({someValue: 10}, () => console.log(this.state.someValue)); // definitely will be 10.
```

Syntax for setState -:

```
this.setState({ //properties and value },//callback function to be executed);
```